# TabNavigator trailing through all the tabs when changing the tab

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, react-native-ios, tabnavigator

Im using TabNavigator of react-navigation in my react-native app and when I tap from 1st tab to 4th tab, it gives me a glimpse of 2nd and 3rd tab too while transitioning to 4th tab. Is there anyway to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- add `animationEnabled:false,` in tabNavigatorConfig. But I would suggest not to beacuse when routuing from first to 4th tab animation gives transition effect which looks good in app